# What is the Unix/Linux equivalent of Typing Tutor?

Tags: linux, typing

Back when I started to use computers, there used to be an application called 'Typing Tutor'. As the name of the application indicates, Typing Tutor was meant to teach computer users to touch-type. To the best of my memory however this application ran only on Windows.

What is the Unix/Linux equivalent of Typing Tutor?

Comment: +1 if yours came in a blue box with both 3.5 and 5.25 floppies!

Comment: @Jonsca: Afraid not )+: 
This was back when, in India, computer magazines were just beginning to bundle shareware/freeware goodies on a disc quarterly or so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be [GNU Typist](http://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/).